# Is my fire animation rendering right?

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to make an animation of fire, but while it's rendering it just looks like a big gray box where the fire is supposed to be. Is this normal?

[image]

Comment: I feel stupid now.

Comment: Wait. That wasn't the problem still looks like that, please help.

Comment: will you add a screen shoot of the material nodes for the material on the smoke domain.

Comment: It looks like the domain object has a diffuse shader applied to the surface.  Smoke domains should **only** have a *volume* shader (using a *density* attribute node).

Comment: @someonewithpc That will hide the smoke too.